# Jenkins configuration: can't see "MSBuild SonarQube Runner" section

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I can see this part in my local installed Jenkins server, but can't find it in my company's Jenkins servers. What's missing to make it show? The SonarQube Runner and Sonar sections are there.

[image: MSBuild SonarQube Runner part is not showing]

Comment: Can you elaborate ? DId you check the logs on server side for part which shows info about plugin /extension loading ?

Comment: I don't see the MSBuild SonarQube Runner section when I go to Manage Jenkins --> Configure System. How can I make it appear? The SonarQube plugin is installed. There is no relevant log message in three log files. The screenshot is from my local server which has this configuration section.

Answer (score 0):

The Compatibility section tells only supported by C# plugin 4.4 onwards:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild.
So the solution is upgrade the C# plugin in SonarQube.